# InfluxDB Regular Expression

Tags: influxdb

All

I have database named `fenetto_data` in `influxdb`. In that I have a table named `metrics` that have following fields

- volt
- humidity
- watt

for example I'm creating retention policy on database `fernetto_data`

```
create retention policy "rp_14days" on "fernetto_data" duration 14d     replication 1 shard duration 1d
```

by using this retention policy I'm creating continuous query

->

```
create continuous query "cq_5m_rollups" on "fernetto_data" 
      resample for 14d
      begin
          select mean(/./) into "rp_14days"."metrics.5m" from "metrics" group by time(5m)
      end
```

this will create new table named `metrics.5m`

and this is storing fields of the form

- mean_volt
- mean_humidity
- mean_watt

but my requirement is `metrics.5m` is also need to store field name same as metrics

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to be more explicit in your CQ. Try changing your CQ to something more like this.

```
CREATE CONTINUOUS QUERY "cq_5m_rollups"
 ON "fernetto_data" RESAMPLE FOR 14d
 BEGIN
  SELECT mean(volt) AS volt,
         mean(humidity) AS humidity,
         mean(watt) AS watt
  INTO "rp_14days"."metrics.5m" FROM "metrics" GROUP BY time(5m)
 END
```

This kind of this can be particularly painful when you have many different field, but should work for your use case.

Comment: is there any way without hardcoding the field names explicitly ?

Comment: Not without changing the field names.